# link rel="stylesheet" doesn't work in MSIE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, browser, cross-browser

The code below works in all browsers(FF, CHROME, OPERA) exclude MSIE! I've tried different code:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="drawable/icon.png">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://127.0.0.1:6789/Resource/raw/styles.css">
```

and

```
<style type="text/css">
@import url(http://127.0.0.1:6789/Resource/raw/styles.css);
</style>
```

But it doesn't work! When I save this web page on a local disk (C:\tmp\webpage.html, for example) and start it from MSIE it works fine! Can anybody explain what can I do? Thanks.

Comment: I bet it's MSIE's security settings at play, given that you're accessing localhost on a different port.

Comment: I don't think so, cos I it the following code works fine: `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://127.0.0.1:6789/Resource/raw/jquery_dialogs.js"></script>`

Comment: The css file is reachable at this ipaddress and port from your tomcat/apache webserver?

Answer (score -3):

give this a try maybe msie was looking for the **media** attribute

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" type="text/css" href="http://127.0.0.1:6789/Resource/raw/styles.css">
```

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_mediatypes.asp